# Is there any reincarnation of Ma Saraswati?

Tags: avatars, devi, saraswati, birth

Does any reference of Ma Sarswati being reincarnated as another Devi?

Ancient Sharada Peeth in Pakistan occupied Kashmir is one of the oldest surviving temples of Saraswati. Is there any other temple of Ma- Saraswati in incarnation form?

Comment: It is very difficult to establish an incarnation.  Even in the case of incarnations of Vishnu or Shiva there are differences of opinions. What will be the criteria based on which one can be declared as an incarnation? It is mainly the ardent devotees of a particular saint that start the concept of incarnation.

Comment: For example Sri Ramakrishna paramhansa was declared by one brAhmani as the incarnation of gadhAdhar or Vishnu. Was this accepted by all? Sri Ramakrishna paramhansa himself never started so.  However, Sri Ramakrishna paramhansa said that Sri Sarada Devi, his wife, was none other than incarnation of Saraswati. He was a great Saint. So We can accept his words.  However, for putting those words of Sri Ramakrishna paramhansa, we don't have scriptural base

Comment: Yes I meant this connection.

Comment: I could not get you.  Do you want me to Post on Sri Sarada Devi?

Comment: Hey sorry, I mean that if any such incarnation of Ma Saraswati has been referenced in other purana?

Comment: Not sure about incarnation in India BUT because of Rishi Durwasa's curse, Goddess Saraswati did incarnate in Gandharva Loka by name of "Madalasa".

Comment: Hey it seems quite intersting , Can you please share the full incident?

Comment: Don't have reference right now to show in asnwer. Besides that's different question than you are asking in this post. You have to ask this in different post. Your current question is only about India, but my shown info is outside the scope of your quesiton.

Comment: ok I am editing my question first of all

Comment: ok @Rishabh one another question, is there any proof in scripture ? I also found the same thing in this blog. https://adziesinghviews.blogspot.com/2019/04/the-unknown-married-life-of-vishnu-and.html

Comment: Sorry, Don't know which scripture describes this story. This is why I told you in comment coz don't have any reference to post as answer.

Comment: @Rishabh :Madalasa was a queen, who took re-birth in the house of Naga King.  The Naga king, with the blessings of Saraswati, performed music, which pleased Shiva (http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/markandeyapurana13.html)

Comment: @TalkisCheapShowmeCode: Tara was considered to be incarnation of Saraswati.  Tara temple is available in Kolkatta.

Comment: Thank you sir, Can you share the full incident?

Comment: @TalkisCheapShowmeCode: Please go through this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saraswati#Avatars).  For Tara temple please read this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarapith).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does any reference of Ma Sarswati being reincarnated as another Devi?

As per [Shiva Purāna: Umā-Saṃhitā: Chapter 48 - The manifestation of Sarasvatī](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226608.html), the goddess who was slayer of Śumbha was an incarnation of Sarasvatī:

> 50. Thus was the goddess, slayer of Śumbha born. She is said to be Sarasvatī. O king, she has manifested herself as a part of Umā.